# Error from IJCA journal Referencing

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

please am writing a conference paper for IJCA. But I notice i can reference successfully using BibTeX, am getting some errors. And the line of bibliography isn't coming. Please can any body help with that

BIBTEX, which is easily invoked via
\begin{verbatim}
\bibliographystyle{ijcaArticle}
\bibliography{damiTex}
\end{verbatim}
 where the damiTex is a jab-ref folder containing a list of my references. 
cant invoke or call it.

Comment: Please help us to help you. If we can't see the document we can't help you. Remove the content and irrelevant packages, just leave the bibliography part and paste your code here in the form of a Minimum (Non)-working example.

Comment: Why are you placing the instructions `\bibliographystyle{ijcaArticle}` and `\bibliography{damiTex}` inside a `verbatim` environment?

Comment: it was from the journal template..... do i have to remove the verbatim??